# Manipulating URL/array to remove the last element

Tags: javascript, jquery, array, url

Is there a better way to do this using chaining?

```js
var url = "www.mycompany.com/sites/demo/t1"
var x = url.split('/');
console.log(x);
var y = x.pop();
console.log(y,x);
var z = x.join("/");
console.log(z);
```

I tried something like but wouldn't work since pop just returns the last value and not the rest:

```
 parentUrl = self.attr('Url').split("/").pop().join("/");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pop()` mutates the underlying list: it removes the last item (and returns it).

It seems you're looking for `slice`:

```
"www.mycompany.com/sites/demo/t1".split('/').slice(0, -1).join('/')
// -> gives: "www.mycompany.com/sites/demo"
```

`.slice(0, -1)` gives the elements of the list from the start until the end minus one item.

However, this is a very poor solution to drop the last path element from a URL. In particular, splitting a string to an array, drop the last element and join the string again is inefficient. It would be better to use `lastIndexOf` to find the position of the last `/`, and then `substr` to extract the part of the string before the last `/`.

```
var s = "www.mycompany.com/sites/demo/t1";
s.substr(0, s.lastIndexOf('/'));
```